# Twilio programmable voice client throwing 31000 error

Tags: objective-c, twilio

I'm using the Twilio Programmable Voice SDK v2.0.0-beta2 and I get a 31000 error whenever I try to initiate a call.

Here is the method I'm triggering

```
- (void)makeCall:(NSString *)capabilityToken
{
  self.outboundCall = [[VoiceClient sharedInstance] call:capabilityToken params:@{@"To": @"+46703709824"} delegate:self];
}
```

Here is the logs:

```
2016-10-04 23:51:08.224 Bitcall[933:13772] SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert
2016-10-04 23:51:15.075 Bitcall[933:13654] Destination number +46735266067
2016-10-04 23:51:15.731 Bitcall[933:13654] ACCESS TOKEN eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCAidHlwIjogIkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiAiQUNhNTM3NGVlZDk3YTM5YTIyODdkMTFlZTM1NWNiYjNiNCIsICJzY29wZSI6ICJzY29wZTpjbGllbnQ6b3V0Z29pbmc_YXBwU2lkPUFQMDg5NDg2MDgxYjY3NGI4M2FmZTBmOTczODNiMjZkNTEmY2xpZW50TmFtZT1hZjdmM2IwOC02Njc0LTRiNzktYjZiNS1iM2I5ZGFhMzg0MjIgc2NvcGU6Y2xpZW50OmluY29taW5nP2NsaWVudE5hbWU9YWY3ZjNiMDgtNjY3NC00Yjc5LWI2YjUtYjNiOWRhYTM4NDIyIiwgImV4cCI6IDE0NzU2MjE0NzV9.-6-Q2rUfgbOzhU2HGt5sPYIRy4VFk9zPdrVpeh0pXIc
WARNING: no real random source present!
2016-10-04 23:51:15.878 Bitcall[933:13654] PJSIP(4): sip_endpoint.c  Module "mod-pjsua-log" unregistered
2016-10-04 23:51:15.878 Bitcall[933:13654] PJSIP(4): sip_endpoint.c  Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
2016-10-04 23:51:15.879 Bitcall[933:13654] [DEBUG TwilioReachability] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2016-10-04 23:51:15.879 Bitcall[933:13654] [DEBUG TVOCommandHandler] Inside postCommand:, received command of type TVOMakeCallCommand
2016-10-04 23:51:15.879 Bitcall[933:13654] Outgoing call (null):
2016-10-04 23:51:15.879 Bitcall[933:14354] [VERBOSE Twilio] Inside constructUri: Registration URL: sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;transport=tls
2016-10-04 23:51:15.880 Bitcall[933:14354] [INFO TVOMakeCallCommand] Call URI: sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;transport=tls
2016-10-04 23:51:15.880 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4):   pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #0 to sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;transport=tls
2016-10-04 23:51:15.880 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4):    pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2
2016-10-04 23:51:15.881 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4):    pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
2016-10-04 23:51:15.881 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4): coreaudio_dev.  ...Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
2016-10-04 23:51:16.202 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4): coreaudio_dev.  ...core audio stream started
2016-10-04 23:51:16.203 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4):    pjsua_acc.c  .Warning: cannot use source TCP/TLS socket address for Contact when nameserver is configured.
2016-10-04 23:51:16.203 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  .UAC dialog created
2016-10-04 23:51:16.203 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ..Session count inc to 2 by mod-pjsua
2016-10-04 23:51:16.204 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4):  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
2016-10-04 23:51:16.204 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4):  pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 10.0.1.13:4738
2016-10-04 23:51:16.204 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4):  pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 10.0.1.13:4739
2016-10-04 23:51:16.205 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(4):  pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 0
2016-10-04 23:51:16.205 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ..Session count dec to 2 by mod-pjsua
2016-10-04 23:51:16.206 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  .Module mod-invite added as dialog usage, data=0x7f87f187e638
2016-10-04 23:51:16.206 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ..Session count inc to 4 by mod-invite
2016-10-04 23:51:16.206 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  .Module mod-100rel added as dialog usage, data=0x7f87f187e864
2016-10-04 23:51:16.206 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  .100rel module attached
2016-10-04 23:51:16.207 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): inv0x7f87ef089  .UAC invite session created for dialog dlg0x7f87ef0898a8
2016-10-04 23:51:16.207 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5):       endpoint  .Request msg INVITE/cseq=5853 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600) created.
2016-10-04 23:51:16.207 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): inv0x7f87ef089  ..Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=5853 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.208 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ...Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=5853 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.208 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  ....Transaction created for Request msg INVITE/cseq=5852 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.208 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  ...Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=5852 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600) in state Null
2016-10-04 23:51:16.208 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5):  sip_resolve.c  ....Starting async DNS SRV query: target=_sips._tcp.chunderm.gll.twilio.com, transport=TLS, port=0
2016-10-04 23:51:16.209 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu  ....Starting async DNS SRV query_job: target=_sips._tcp.chunderm.gll.twilio.com:5061
2016-10-04 23:51:16.209 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  ....State changed from Null to Calling, event=TX_MSG
2016-10-04 23:51:16.209 Bitcall[933:14354] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  .....Transaction tsx0x7f87ef8d5ea8 state changed to Calling
2016-10-04 23:51:16.210 Bitcall[933:14354] [DEBUG Twilio] Inside on_call_state(), call: 0x6100000ab160, internal state: 0
2016-10-04 23:51:16.210 Bitcall[933:14354] [VERBOSE Twilio] Inside on_call_state(), PJSIP_INV_STATE_CALLING
2016-10-04 23:51:16.210 Bitcall[933:14354] [VERBOSE TVOOutgoingCall] handlePJSIPInviteStateCalling. Error: (null)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.211 Bitcall[933:14354] [VERBOSE Twilio] on_call_tsx_state(), state: 1, status_code: 0: (null)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.214 Bitcall[933:14869] PJSIP(5): coreaudio_dev. !Recorder thread started, (186 frames)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.214 Bitcall[933:14869] PJSIP(4): os_core_unix.c  Info: possibly re-registering existing thread
2016-10-04 23:51:16.214 Bitcall[933:14869] PJSIP(5): coreaudio_dev. !Player thread started, (186 frames)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.300 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5):     resolver.c !Received 208 bytes DNS response from 0.0.0.0:0
2016-10-04 23:51:16.300 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu  SRV query_job for _sips._tcp.chunderm.gll.twilio.com completed, 2 of 2 total entries selected:
2016-10-04 23:51:16.301 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu   0: SRV 10 100 10194 chunderm0.ie1.twilio.com (-)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.301 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu   1: SRV 10 100 10194 chunderm1.ie1.twilio.com (-)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.301 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu  Starting async DNS A query_job for chunderm0.ie1.twilio.com
2016-10-04 23:51:16.302 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu  Starting async DNS A query_job for chunderm1.ie1.twilio.com
2016-10-04 23:51:16.336 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5):     resolver.c  Received 82 bytes DNS response from 0.0.0.0:0
2016-10-04 23:51:16.336 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu  DNS A for chunderm1.ie1.twilio.com: 54.77.198.98
2016-10-04 23:51:16.338 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5):     resolver.c  Received 82 bytes DNS response from 0.0.0.0:0
2016-10-04 23:51:16.338 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu  DNS A for chunderm0.ie1.twilio.com: 54.77.198.97
2016-10-04 23:51:16.339 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): _sips._tcp.chu  Server resolution complete, 2 server entry(s) found
2016-10-04 23:51:16.340 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4): tlsc0x7f87ef8d  TLS client transport created
2016-10-04 23:51:16.341 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4): tlsc0x7f87ef8d  TLS transport 10.0.1.13:49890 is connecting to chunderm.gll.twilio.com:10194...
2016-10-04 23:51:16.341 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4):   pjsua_core.c  TX 1640 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=5852 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600) to TLS 54.77.198.97:10194:
INVITE sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;transport=tls SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.1.13:49890;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj6pwHrMIMhtKXvfx-x.DL.t7GJcfMqWks;alias
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:twilio@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;tag=oYtIkaN9gJYkJKjk.xpFFcCDOQ0Rpx54
To: sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com
Contact: <sip:twilio@10.0.1.13:49889;transport=TLS;ob>
Call-ID: ajhuX1WDhrm50Pln9YT0A0NtvV91wZL8
CSeq: 5852 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 14400
Min-SE: 90
X-Twilio-Client: {"p":"ios","v":"2.0.0","mobile":{"arch":"i386","product":"iPhone","name":"x86_64","v":"10.0"}}
User-Agent: TwilioProgrammableVoice.iOS/2.0
X-Twilio-AccessToken: eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCAidHlwIjogIkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiAiQUNhNTM3NGVlZDk3YTM5YTIyODdkMTFlZTM1NWNiYjNiNCIsICJzY29wZSI6ICJzY29wZTpjbGllbnQ6b3V0Z29pbmc_YXBwU2lkPUFQMDg5NDg2MDgxYjY3NGI4M2FmZTBmOTczODNiMjZkNTEmY2xpZW50TmFtZT1hZjdmM2IwOC02Njc0LTRiNzktYjZiNS1iM2I5ZGFhMzg0MjIgc2NvcGU6Y2xpZW50OmluY29taW5nP2NsaWVudE5hbWU9YWY3ZjNiMDgtNjY3NC00Yjc5LWI2YjUtYjNiOWRhYTM4NDIyIiwgImV4cCI6IDE0NzU2MjE0NzV9.-6-Q2rUfgbOzhU2HGt5sPYIRy4VFk9zPdrVpeh0pXIc
X-Twilio-ClientVersion: 3
X-Twilio-Params: To=%2B46703707828
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   317

v=0
o=- 3684606676 3684606676 IN IP4 10.0.1.13
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4738 RTP/AVP 98 97 0 96
c=IN IP4 10.0.1.13
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4739 IN IP4 10.0.1.13
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:96 0-16

--end msg--
2016-10-04 23:51:16.561 Bitcall[933:14834] [DEBUG Twilio] on_transport_state(): 0
2016-10-04 23:51:16.562 Bitcall[933:14834] [DEBUG Twilio] ------>Transport connected: 0xef8d8628, inside transportConnected:
2016-10-04 23:51:16.562 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4): tlsc0x7f87ef8d  TLS transport 10.0.1.13:49890 is connected to chunderm.gll.twilio.com:10194
2016-10-04 23:51:16.624 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): sip_endpoint.c  Processing incoming message: Response msg 302/INVITE/cseq=5852 (rdata0x7f87ef8d8940)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.624 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] Inside on_rx_response(): received INVITE response, rewriting contact
2016-10-04 23:51:16.624 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4):   pjsua_core.c  .RX 474 bytes Response msg 302/INVITE/cseq=5852 (rdata0x7f87ef8d8940) from TLS 54.77.198.97:10194:
SIP/2.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.1.13:49890;received=79.138.84.69;rport=45271;branch=z9hG4bKPj6pwHrMIMhtKXvfx-x.DL.t7GJcfMqWks;alias
From: sip:twilio@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;tag=oYtIkaN9gJYkJKjk.xpFFcCDOQ0Rpx54
To: sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;tag=d47538de3dc305e6ad30a3af17018f93.8b2e
Call-ID: ajhuX1WDhrm50Pln9YT0A0NtvV91wZL8
CSeq: 5852 INVITE
Contact: <sip:54.154.182.131:10194;transport=tls>
Server: Twilio Client SBC
Content-Length: 0


--end msg--
2016-10-04 23:51:16.625 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  .Incoming Response msg 302/INVITE/cseq=5852 (rdata0x7f87ef8d8940) in state Calling
2016-10-04 23:51:16.625 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5):       endpoint  ..Request msg ACK/cseq=5852 (tdta0x7f87ef08f200) created.
2016-10-04 23:51:16.649 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4):   pjsua_core.c  ..TX 413 bytes Request msg ACK/cseq=5852 (tdta0x7f87ef08f200) to TLS 54.77.198.97:10194:
ACK sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;transport=tls SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.1.13:49890;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj6pwHrMIMhtKXvfx-x.DL.t7GJcfMqWks;alias
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:twilio@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;tag=oYtIkaN9gJYkJKjk.xpFFcCDOQ0Rpx54
To: sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;tag=d47538de3dc305e6ad30a3af17018f93.8b2e
Call-ID: ajhuX1WDhrm50Pln9YT0A0NtvV91wZL8
CSeq: 5852 ACK
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
2016-10-04 23:51:16.649 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  ..State changed from Calling to Completed, event=RX_MSG
2016-10-04 23:51:16.649 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ...Received Response msg 302/INVITE/cseq=5852 (rdata0x7f87ef8d8940)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.650 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ...Transaction tsx0x7f87ef8d5ea8 state changed to Completed
2016-10-04 23:51:16.650 Bitcall[933:14834] [DEBUG Twilio] In on_call_redirected, call_id: 0, target: 0x7f87f187e97c, pjsip_event: 0x700004578720
2016-10-04 23:51:16.650 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  .....Session count inc to 3 by mod-invite
2016-10-04 23:51:16.651 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  .....Session count dec to 3 by mod-invite
2016-10-04 23:51:16.651 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): inv0x7f87ef089  .....Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=5852 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.651 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ......Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=5852 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.651 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87f1135  .......Transaction created for Request msg INVITE/cseq=5853 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.651 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87f1135  ......Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=5853 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600) in state Null
2016-10-04 23:51:16.652 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5):  sip_resolve.c  .......Target '54.154.182.131:10194' type=TLS resolved to '54.154.182.131:10194' type=TLS (TLS transport)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.652 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4): tlsc0x7f87ef0f  .......TLS client transport created
2016-10-04 23:51:16.652 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4): tlsc0x7f87ef0f  .......TLS transport 10.0.1.13:49891 is connecting to 54.154.182.131:10194...
2016-10-04 23:51:16.652 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4):   pjsua_core.c  .......TX 1632 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=5853 (tdta0x7f87f10f6600) to TLS 54.154.182.131:10194:
INVITE sip:54.154.182.131:10194;transport=tls SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.1.13:49891;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjyhINfNL4knngL3XhPrtNN.1SeC2AGB.-;alias
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:twilio@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;tag=oYtIkaN9gJYkJKjk.xpFFcCDOQ0Rpx54
To: sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com
Contact: <sip:twilio@10.0.1.13:49889;transport=TLS;ob>
Call-ID: ajhuX1WDhrm50Pln9YT0A0NtvV91wZL8
CSeq: 5853 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 14400
Min-SE: 90
X-Twilio-Client: {"p":"ios","v":"2.0.0","mobile":{"arch":"i386","product":"iPhone","name":"x86_64","v":"10.0"}}
User-Agent: TwilioProgrammableVoice.iOS/2.0
X-Twilio-AccessToken: eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCAidHlwIjogIkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiAiQUNhNTM3NGVlZDk3YTM5YTIyODdkMTFlZTM1NWNiYjNiNCIsICJzY29wZSI6ICJzY29wZTpjbGllbnQ6b3V0Z29pbmc_YXBwU2lkPUFQMDg5NDg2MDgxYjY3NGI4M2FmZTBmOTczODNiMjZkNTEmY2xpZW50TmFtZT1hZjdmM2IwOC02Njc0LTRiNzktYjZiNS1iM2I5ZGFhMzg0MjIgc2NvcGU6Y2xpZW50OmluY29taW5nP2NsaWVudE5hbWU9YWY3ZjNiMDgtNjY3NC00Yjc5LWI2YjUtYjNiOWRhYTM4NDIyIiwgImV4cCI6IDE0NzU2MjE0NzV9.-6-Q2rUfgbOzhU2HGt5sPYIRy4VFk9zPdrVpeh0pXIc
X-Twilio-ClientVersion: 3
X-Twilio-Params: To=%2B46703707828
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   317

v=0
o=- 3684606676 3684606676 IN IP4 10.0.1.13
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4738 RTP/AVP 98 97 0 96
c=IN IP4 10.0.1.13
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4739 IN IP4 10.0.1.13
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:96 0-16

--end msg--
2016-10-04 23:51:16.653 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87f1135  .......State changed from Null to Calling, event=TX_MSG
2016-10-04 23:51:16.653 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ........Transaction tsx0x7f87f11354a8 state changed to Calling
2016-10-04 23:51:16.653 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] on_call_tsx_state(), state: 1, status_code: 0: (null)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.653 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] on_call_tsx_state(), state: 4, status_code: 302: Moved Temporarily
2016-10-04 23:51:16.653 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  Timeout timer event
2016-10-04 23:51:16.653 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  .State changed from Completed to Terminated, event=TIMER
2016-10-04 23:51:16.654 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ..Transaction tsx0x7f87ef8d5ea8 state changed to Terminated
2016-10-04 23:51:16.654 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] on_call_tsx_state(), state: 6, status_code: 302: Moved Temporarily
2016-10-04 23:51:16.654 Bitcall[933:14834] [DEBUG Twilio] ------>Destroying transport: 0x7f87ef8d8628, inside releaseTransport
2016-10-04 23:51:16.658 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  Timeout timer event
2016-10-04 23:51:16.658 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  .State changed from Terminated to Destroyed, event=TIMER
2016-10-04 23:51:16.659 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tdta0x7f87ef08  ..Destroying txdata Request msg ACK/cseq=5852 (tdta0x7f87ef08f200)
2016-10-04 23:51:16.659 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87ef8d5  Transaction destroyed!
2016-10-04 23:51:16.919 Bitcall[933:14834] [DEBUG Twilio] on_transport_state(): 0
2016-10-04 23:51:16.919 Bitcall[933:14834] [DEBUG Twilio] ------>Transport connected: 0xef0fce28, inside transportConnected:
2016-10-04 23:51:16.919 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4): tlsc0x7f87ef0f  TLS transport 10.0.1.13:49891 is connected to 54.154.182.131:10194
2016-10-04 23:51:17.175 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): sip_endpoint.c  Processing incoming message: Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=5853 (rdata0x7f87ef0fd140)
2016-10-04 23:51:17.176 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] Inside on_rx_response(): received INVITE response, rewriting contact
2016-10-04 23:51:17.176 Bitcall[933:14834] [WARN Twilio]  .. cannot rewrite contact -> no contact
2016-10-04 23:51:17.177 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4):   pjsua_core.c  .RX 363 bytes Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=5853 (rdata0x7f87ef0fd140) from TLS 54.154.182.131:10194:
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
CSeq: 5853 INVITE
Call-ID: ajhuX1WDhrm50Pln9YT0A0NtvV91wZL8
From: <sip:twilio@chunderm.gll.twilio.com>;tag=oYtIkaN9gJYkJKjk.xpFFcCDOQ0Rpx54
To: <sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.1.13:49891;rport=46432;branch=z9hG4bKPjyhINfNL4knngL3XhPrtNN.1SeC2AGB.-;alias;received=79.138.84.69
Server: Twilio
Content-Length: 0


--end msg--
2016-10-04 23:51:17.177 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87f1135  .Incoming Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=5853 (rdata0x7f87ef0fd140) in state Calling
2016-10-04 23:51:17.178 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87f1135  ..State changed from Calling to Proceeding, event=RX_MSG
2016-10-04 23:51:17.178 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ...Received Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=5853 (rdata0x7f87ef0fd140)
2016-10-04 23:51:17.178 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ...Transaction tsx0x7f87f11354a8 state changed to Proceeding
2016-10-04 23:51:17.179 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] on_call_tsx_state(), state: 3, status_code: 100: Trying
2016-10-04 23:51:17.268 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): sip_endpoint.c  Processing incoming message: Response msg 403/INVITE/cseq=5853 (rdata0x7f87ef0fd140)
2016-10-04 23:51:17.269 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] Inside on_rx_response(): received INVITE response, rewriting contact
2016-10-04 23:51:17.269 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4):   pjsua_core.c  .RX 557 bytes Response msg 403/INVITE/cseq=5853 (rdata0x7f87ef0fd140) from TLS 54.154.182.131:10194:
SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
CSeq: 5853 INVITE
Call-ID: ajhuX1WDhrm50Pln9YT0A0NtvV91wZL8
From: <sip:twilio@chunderm.gll.twilio.com>;tag=oYtIkaN9gJYkJKjk.xpFFcCDOQ0Rpx54
To: <sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com>;tag=74908818_6772d868_cba51b64-75b3-401c-9e09-f1c2ad3e4e29
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.1.13:49891;rport=46432;branch=z9hG4bKPjyhINfNL4knngL3XhPrtNN.1SeC2AGB.-;alias;received=79.138.84.69
Server: Twilio
Contact: <sip:ec2-54-154-182-131.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:10194;transport=tls>
X-Twilio-Error: 31201 Authentication failed
Content-Length: 0


--end msg--
2016-10-04 23:51:17.270 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87f1135  .Incoming Response msg 403/INVITE/cseq=5853 (rdata0x7f87ef0fd140) in state Proceeding
2016-10-04 23:51:17.270 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5):       endpoint  ..Request msg ACK/cseq=5853 (tdta0x7f87f0160400) created.
2016-10-04 23:51:17.271 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(4):   pjsua_core.c  ..TX 422 bytes Request msg ACK/cseq=5853 (tdta0x7f87f0160400) to TLS 54.154.182.131:10194:
ACK sip:54.154.182.131:10194;transport=tls SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.1.13:49891;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjyhINfNL4knngL3XhPrtNN.1SeC2AGB.-;alias
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:twilio@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;tag=oYtIkaN9gJYkJKjk.xpFFcCDOQ0Rpx54
To: sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;tag=74908818_6772d868_cba51b64-75b3-401c-9e09-f1c2ad3e4e29
Call-ID: ajhuX1WDhrm50Pln9YT0A0NtvV91wZL8
CSeq: 5853 ACK
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
2016-10-04 23:51:17.271 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): tsx0x7f87f1135  ..State changed from Proceeding to Completed, event=RX_MSG
2016-10-04 23:51:17.272 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ...Received Response msg 403/INVITE/cseq=5853 (rdata0x7f87ef0fd140)
2016-10-04 23:51:17.272 Bitcall[933:14834] PJSIP(5): dlg0x7f87ef089  ...Transaction tsx0x7f87f11354a8 state changed to Completed
2016-10-04 23:51:17.273 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] on_call_tsx_state(), state: 4, status_code: 403: Forbidden
2016-10-04 23:51:17.273 Bitcall[933:14834] [DEBUG Twilio] Inside on_call_state(), call: 0x6100000ab160, internal state: 0
2016-10-04 23:51:17.273 Bitcall[933:14834] [VERBOSE Twilio] Inside on_call_state(), PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED, internal state: 0, last_status: 403
2016-10-04 23:51:17.273 Bitcall[933:14834] [WARN Twilio] Inside Twilio.transp
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Got an answer from Twilio. You can view it here https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-objc/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this issue was to migrate to the new type capability tokens called access tokens which ships in their latest python wrapper. Release Candidate 11.